# DbNetGrid - Change language in DbNetSuite

Tags: client-server, lang

I'm using DbNetGrid on client-side programming. I need to change the default language to Spanish, I already ask to them in their Contact Form, and their answers are not working for me.

First, my default language in the browser is Spanish.

I tried to put this in my web.config:

```
<add key="DbNetSuiteCultureSource" value="server"/>
```

+

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es" />
```

Also in the client:

```
var dbnetgrid1 = new DbNetGrid("dbnetgrid1");
with (dbnetgrid1)
{
  connectionString = "SamplesDatabase"
  ...
  userLanguage = "es-ES"
  ...
  initialize()
}
```

Moreover, in the call:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="./js/DbNetSuite.js.ashx?userlanguage=es-ES"></script>
```

So, is anybody using this software? I have many problems with it, please, any idea, answer me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DbNetGrid on client-side programming also and i had the same problem 
in Arabic i tried all these some worked in some projects and other not

try this in appsetting 
add <-key="DbNetSuiteVSCultureSource" value="server" />